# How to improve react form performance (with formik)?

Tags: reactjs, forms, performance, formik

In a formik form with many inputs (like 40 fields), I can see that the form is slow.

This is my formik configuration :

```js
const formik = useFormik({
        enableReinitialize: true,
        initialValues: contractor,
        validateOnBlur: true,
        validateOnChange: false,
        validateOnMount: true,
        validationSchema: // YUP validation here
      });
```

This is how I define fields :

```
    <TextField
      variant="outlined"
      fullWidth
      id="No"
      name="No"
      label="No"
      value={formik.values.No}
      onChange={formik.handleChange}
      onBlur={handleSubmit}
      error={Boolean(formik.errors.No)}
      helperText={formik.errors.No}
/>
```

Is react bad for handling huge forms? How can I improve formik performance? What i'm doing wrong?

Thank you !

Comment: Do you update  state in some of your inputs?

Comment: States are handled by formik, I imagine the whole form is updated automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to run the app on production enviroment.
"using create react app and semantic ui i built ~40 fields. input is very slow whilst running the app in dev mode. but when i run yarn build and run the app with serve -s build, there is no delay in input fields."

taken from this issue, take a look i think it'll be very helpful.
https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/671

Moreover, sometimes it's not only about formik and the high number of fields only,
sometimes it's about performance, maybe there are unexpected re-renders that take a long or a huge calculation that can cause this kind of latency/performance issue.
I suggest trying with react dev-tools extension, and figuring out if there is any laggy component or any calculation that is responsible for that situation.

react docs - react dev-tools :
https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler.html

Answer (score 4):

Did you try `[FastField][1]`?

It says:

> FastField is an optimized version of Field meant to be used on
> large forms (~30+ fields) or when a field has very expensive
> validation requirements.

While researching how to handle similar problem, I bumped into it.

Nevertheless, in my case it was something else: `validateOnChange: false` improved the performance tremendously.

Initially I thought the problem was rerendering. The `formik` object was passed around as prop and forms keystrokes in child components triggered rerender of the parent. Even after moving the `formik` instance in the children, the performance was not noticeably improved. Setting `validateOnChange` to `false` did the trick.

In your case you have it already set, so maybe split the forms into several pages (wizard). Or the user has to change all 40 fields at once?